# Is there a way to align just one line of text to right in KivyMD List?

Tags: python, list, listview, kivymd

I am trying to get this one line of text in ThreeLineListItem in KivyMD to align right and not able to find a solution. Is there any property that will allow me to do so or is there any other alternative solution ?

```
listitem=ThreeLineListItem(
                    text= f'First Line that I want right aligned',
                    secondary_text= f'SecondLine',
                    tertiary_text=f'ThirdLine'  
                )
            self.ids['scroll'].add_widget(listitem)
```

Answer (score 0):

well you could try this if it helps let me know

```
    listitem.ids._lbl_secondary.pos_hint = {"right":2}
```

the above puts secondary_text to the right,  if you want to add the tertiary_text to the right change the id to _lbl_tertiary the same applies for text change the id to  _lbl_primary. Check out the documentation